# Unable to Install Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 3.0.0

Tags: c++-winrt

Using NuGet Package Manager, I get this error message:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 3.0.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.           0
```

The app is a Blank App (C++/winRT). Visual Studio 15.8.0 Preview 4.0.(10.0.17134.0, 10.0.17704.0)

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's name, the Windows Community Toolkit is only intended for C# developers.